# Multiselect down arrow selecting value but checkbox is not selected

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm Using `bootstrap Multiselect` , i'm faceing issue when user navigate using down arrow(keyboard) in options in multiselect it is selecting options without selecting checbox

here is my code

```
$(function () {

            $('[id*=lstSecondaryComment]').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true,
                numberDisplayed: 0,
                buttonWidth: '200px',
                numberDisplayed: 0

            }

            );
        });
```

im appyling `multislect to Listbox (ASP.NET)` , i want to disable navigation arrows or atlst it should select `checkbox` in list

Any help Appriciated

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, please add:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){     
  $('#lstSecondaryComment').multiselect(); 
}); 
</script>
```

Would also be more insightful if you included your html Markup and where you included relevant plugins.